# SQL query - Unable to insert values with date check constrain -

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, constraints, sql-insert

I have table called 'loan' with constrain `Loan_Date < Return_Date`. I'm unable to insert null values to Return date.

Constaint: `CONSTRAINT LOAN_DATE_CK CHECK (Loan_Date < Return_Date)`

My SQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO Loan (Borrower_Id, Copy_Id, Loan_Date ,Return_Date) VALUES
('00001','00001','2014-04-01','2014-04-10'),
('00001','00007','2014-04-10',' ');
```

Error:

```
****Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "LOAN_DATE_CK". The conflict occurred in database "lib_database", table "dbo.Loan".
The statement has been terminated.****
```

I can enter records with both values. Can anyone please help me to correct this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either  Removed the constraint or add another criteria in the constraint and OR it such

```
CONSTRAINT LOAN_DATE_CK CHECK (Loan_Date < Return_Date OR Return_Date is null)
```

and do insert like this

```
INSERT INTO Loan (Borrower_Id, Copy_Id, Loan_Date ,Return_Date) VALUES
('00001','00001','2014-04-01','2014-04-10'),
('00001','00007','2014-04-10', null); --make null value instead of ' ' or ''
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you can change your constraint to something like this : [not tested]

```
 (Loan_Date < ISNULL(Return_Date, '9999-12-01'))
```

In this case, if your return date is null, it will b ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the Loan_Date ,Return_Date fields are of type Date/DateTime - You cannot successfully evaluation a Date data type against a null value (2014-01-01 > or < null) this value will always return false

I Would suggest add an ISNULL check condition to return a static date that you can check against

```
CONSTRAINT LOAN_DATE_CK CHECK (Loan_Date < ISNULL(Return_Date, CAST('CustomDate' as DATE)))
```